# After installing angular-cesium how can I add new access token

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I am using angular-cesium in my Angular project. After following the [guide](https://docs.angular-cesium.com/getting-started/installation) in ,and using the command:

```
ng add angular-cesium
```

The library is ready to use, but it uses the default access token. Where should I replace the default access token with my own generated token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not mentioned in the documentations, but after investigating the code, there is a commented line in the main.ts file where we can supply the access token:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

Cesium.buildModuleUrl.setBaseUrl('/assets/cesium/');
//Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken="";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I can add the token in defaultAccessToken and uncomment the line.